# UWP AutoCompleteBox in ContentDialog not sizing correctly - text area larger than drawn

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, layout, uwp

I have an `AutoCompleteTextBox` in UWP is exhibiting a really odd behavior, and I can't figure out what's causing it.  The `TextBox` is in a `Grid`, but the user can type past the bounds of the `TextBox`, so the first and last characters of each line are hidden behind the surrounding border.  I've taken some screenshots to hopefully make this make more sense, as it's difficult to describe.

I've tried everything I can think of, but can't seem to get it to stop doing this.  The only effect I had at all was in changing the `HorizontalAlignment` of the `TextBox`.  Originally it was `Stretch`, and only the right side of the `TextBox` had cutoff letters.  When I changed it to `Center`, it divided the cut-off section between both the left and right.

Does anybody have any ideas as to what's going on?

*In the 1st picture, the actual `TextBox` area is defined by the box on the far outer edges of the `ContentDialog` [with the drag handles left of the (116)].*

**TextBox in VS Designer**
[image: View in Designer]

*In the second picture, the letters typed in the `TextBox` are 2 W's.  If you look closely, you can just see the very right of the 1st W to the left of the full W there.*

**TextBox during execution**
[image]

**XAML:**

```
<ContentDialog
x:Class="FlipPanelTest2.ComposeTweet"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:FlipPanelTest2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
RequestedTheme="Dark"
Title="{Binding SendTo}"
Foreground="Gray"
Width="600"
PrimaryButtonText="Cancel"
SecondaryButtonText="Tweet!"
SecondaryButtonStyle="{StaticResource TweetContentDialogButtonStyle}"
PrimaryButtonStyle="{StaticResource CancelButtonStyle}"
PrimaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick"
SecondaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_SecondaryButtonClick">
<Grid Width="Auto">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="tweetText" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="2" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" MaxHeight="180" MinHeight="112" Width="540" />        
    <StackPanel x:Name="characterCount" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock x:Name="currentChars" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="10" Text="{Binding TweetCharacters}" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="charsDivider" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="10" Text="/" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="maxChars" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="10" Text="{Binding MaxCharacters}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well some more searching found the answer apparently.  I hadn't thought to search for a max size on the ContentDialog, hence the reason I didn't find this before.  Providing a link to the answer though for future people to use:

Quoted from [ContentDialog max width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917333/contentdialog-max-width):

> In your App.xaml, try setting the ContentDialogMaxWidth to say, 800.
>   The default is 548. You might want to increase the height too.
>
> ```
> <Application.Resources>
>     <x:Double x:Key="ContentDialogMaxWidth">800</x:Double>
>     <x:Double x:Key="ContentDialogMaxHeight">756</x:Double>
> </Application.Resources>
> ```

[ContentDialog max width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917333/contentdialog-max-width)

It's the last answer listed there, for some reason not the accepted answer.  :)